# TreeView label editing question

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a treeview with nodes like this: "Foo (1234)", and want to allow the user to rename the nodes, but only the Foo part, without (1234). I first tried to change the node text in `BeforeLabelEdit` like this:

```
private void treeView1_BeforeLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    e.Node.Text = "Foo";
}
```

But when I click the node to edit it, "Foo (1234)" appears in the textbox.

Okay, then let's try something else.

I set `treeView1.LabelEdit` to false, and then do the following:

```
private void treeView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode == treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.Location))
        {
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = "Foo";
            treeView1.LabelEdit = true;
            treeView1.SelectedNode.BeginEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

And then in `AfterLabelEdit`, I set `LabelEdit` back to false.

And guess what? This doesn't work either. It changes the node text to "Foo" but the edit textbox does not appear.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I have found a [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/CustomizedLabelEdit.aspx) to this on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com). Among the comments at the bottom, you will also find a portable solution.

Answer (score 4):

Heh - I struck that one a few years back. I even left a [suggestion on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=94140) (vote for it!) to allow the label to be changed in BeforeLabelEdit.

One option (in WinForms - it's a different story in WPF) is to use custom painting for your TreeNodes so that the actual label is still "Foo" and you custom draw the " (1234)" after it. It's a bit of a pain to get right though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to do it with custom painting.
And of course I voted for your suggestion :)